# 64-Bit Ntdll Has x86 Instruction Set?

Tags: windows, winapi, wow64, ntdll

I am trying to disassemble the 64-bit `ntdll.dll` using IDA. From my understand, this DLL is located in `C:\Windows\System32` on a Windows 64-bit OS.  When I disassemble this DLL, it shows 32-bit addresses and a 32-bit instruction set. However, in the debugger, when I load this library into a process from the same directory, it has a 64-bit instruction set during runtime.

How can I disassemble the 64-bit `ntdll`?

Comment: Maybe show more details; which 32-bit values are you talking about exactly?

Comment: @tenfour the instruction set is 32 bit in the disassembler so the registars are like eax instead of rax.

Comment: [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

Comment: You can check if `ntdll.dll` is `64bit` or `32bit` using: `dumpbin /headers "c:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll"`.  It will give you, for example, `8664 machine (x64)` on a Windows 64-bit OS.

Comment: @rit: That doesn't help you understand, which binary you are looking at when using a different tool (like IDA Pro).

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether IDA is a 32 bit application in Task Manager (on the `Processes` page 32 bit processes should have the suffix `(32 bit)`. If you switch to the `Details` page in Task Manager perform a right click on the column header and choose `Select columns` from the context menu. Select `Platform` to display the bit-ness of a process and close the dialog. 32 bit processes are listed as `32 bit` in the `Platform` column.

If IDA is a 32 bit application, use the path `c:\windows\sysnative\ntdll.dll` to open the DLL. If you specify `sysnative` instead of `System32`, Windows uses the `SYSTEM32` directory instead of the `SysWOW64` for 32 bit apps.